# Eclipse won't run; Java exit code 13

Tags: java, eclipse

When opening Eclipse, following error message is shown. Below is my eclipse.ini file.

[image]

eclipse.ini

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20140415-2008.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.200.v20140603-1326
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256M
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.appendVmargs
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6
-Xms40m
-Xmx512m
```

Anyone know what I should do?

Comment: You are using a 64 bit Eclipse and a 32 bit Java. You must use both 64 bit or both 32 bit.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, my solution, not good i think, was unistall java and install it again, also with the jdk, java 1.6 or newer is required.